# Como sumar un carácter a la cadena en php

Tags: php

tengo un duda, me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de sumar un carácter a una cadena es decir:

```
$cadena = '000'
$cadena = '0000' //string sumado
```

Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El [operador de concatenación en PHP](http://php.net/language.operators.string) es el punto (`.`) y se usa así:

```
$a = '-hola-';
$b = '*adios*';
$c = $a . $b;      // La variable $c vale '-hola-*adios*'
```

También se puede usar el operador de asignación sobre concatenación (`.=`) para concatenar el contenido actual a otro nuevo:

```
$a = '-hola-';
$a .= '*adios*';   // La variable $a vale '-hola-*adios*'
```

Comment: hahah estaba escribiendo mi respuesta y me `ninjadeaste`. Puedes añadir el operador `.=` para concatenar y asignar en el mismo paso ^^

Comment: Muy buena idea :) Gracias, también me ha pasado alguna que otra vez contigo u otros x)

Comment: mmmm vale, me dieron una idea muy buenas gracias

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta que ha quedado más o menos igual que en la página del manual de PHP xD

Comment: @JosbertHernandezRiera recuerda que en PHP se deben terminar las líneas de código con el punto y coma (`;`) si no quieres provocar un error de `xx inesperado en línea xx`. Y recuerda también votar la respuesta como correcta si solucionó tu duda.