# Concantenacion con += devuelve 0

Tags: php

Al hacer este ciclo me imprime 0. ¿A qué se debe?

```
$ano = '<select>';
  for($i=date("Y"); $i>=1900; $i--){
     $ano += '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
  }
$ano +='</select>';
echo $ano;
```

Comment: La concatenación en PHP se hace con `.`  y no con `+` (debería ser `$ano .= ` en lugar de `$ano +=`). Voto por cerrar esta pregunta por ser un fallo tipográfico.

Comment: Mas alla del error tipografico, no se podria contestar que esta haciendo += en este caso? o esta generando un error?. tal vez se pueda rescatar la pregunta cambiando el titulo...

Comment: @gbianchi La cosa es que lo hace bien cuando concatena la `$i`, por lo que me imagino que realmente no es un problema de concepto, sino un fallo tipográfico. Y si se cambia la pregunta para que sea sobre cómo concatenar, entonces sería un duplicado de [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/70346/250)

Comment: cuando pone el += intenta interpretar la cadena de texto como un numero, así que intenta hacer 0+0 por ello te devuelve 0

Comment: la de @JorgeArturoJuarez era la respuesta que buscaba.. se puede poner como respuesta? el operador existe, pero no es de concatenacion, si no de suma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te han comentado se usa el . (punto) para concatenar, de hecho lo haces con $i.

Solamente cambia los + por . (punto)

Esto:

```
$ano += '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
```

Por:

```
$ano .= '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
```

---

Esto:

```
$ano +='</select>';
```

Por:

```
$ano .='</select>';
```